# Error 301 when running WebPageTest

Tags: node.js, gulp, webpagetest

i would like to use gulp-sitespeedio@0.0.8 to test my website with webpagetest.
But I get an error on my console and I dont know why. Find anybody my fault?

```
[20:16:26] Starting 'webpagetest:build'...
[20:16:26] Analyze your site’s web performance
info: OS: 'darwin 15.6.0', Node.js: 'v5.1.0', sitespeed.io: '3.5.0', PhantomJS: '1.9.8', java: '1.8.0_31', browsertime: '0.9.4'
info: Using configured web perf budget {"wpt":{"requests":60,"bytesIn":1000000,"SpeedIndex":1000}}
info: Will analyze 2 pages
info: Running WebPageTest http://www.sitespeed.io pollResults=10, timeout=800, firstViewOnly=false, runs=9, private=true, aftRenderingTime=true, location=Dulles:Firefox, connectivity=3G, video=true
info: Running WebPageTest http://www.sitespeed.io/faq/ pollResults=10, timeout=800, firstViewOnly=false, runs=9, private=true, aftRenderingTime=true, location=Dulles:Firefox, connectivity=3G, video=true
error: WebPageTest couldn't fetch info for url http://www.sitespeed.io{ [WPTAPIError: Moved Permanently] name: 'WPTAPIError', code: 301, message: 'Moved Permanently' }
error: Error running WebPageTest: { [WPTAPIError: Moved Permanently] name: 'WPTAPIError', code: 301, message: 'Moved Permanently' }
error: WebPageTest couldn't fetch info for url http://www.sitespeed.io/faq/{ [WPTAPIError: Moved Permanently] name: 'WPTAPIError', code: 301, message: 'Moved Permanently' }
error: Error running WebPageTest: { [WPTAPIError: Moved Permanently] name: 'WPTAPIError', code: 301, message: 'Moved Permanently' }
/Users/.../node_modules/sitespeed.io/lib/util/util.js:279
        return pageData.webpagetest.wpt[0].response.data.testUrl;
                                          ^

TypeError: Cannot read property 'response' of undefined
    at Object.module.exports.getURLFromPageData (/Users/.../node_modules/sitespeed.io/lib/util/util.js:279:43)
    at Object.exports.processPage (/Users/.../node_modules/sitespeed.io/lib/collectors/assetsByTiming.js:25:21)
    at /Users/.../node_modules/sitespeed.io/lib/collector.js:126:7
    at Array.forEach (native)
    at Collector.collectPageData (/Users/.../node_modules/sitespeed.io/lib/collector.js:125:19)
    at processAnalysisResults (/Users/.../node_modules/sitespeed.io/lib/analyze/analyzer.js:171:14)
    at /Users/.../node_modules/sitespeed.io/lib/analyze/analyzer.js:68:7
    at /Users/.../node_modules/async/lib/async.js:254:17
    at /Users/.../node_modules/async/lib/async.js:157:25
    at /Users/.../node_modules/async/lib/async.js:251:21
    at Object.queue.drain (/Users/.../node_modules/sitespeed.io/lib/analyze/webpagetest.js:63:11)
    at next (/Users/.../node_modules/async/lib/async.js:804:31)
    at /Users/.../node_modules/async/lib/async.js:32:16
    at /Users/.../node_modules/sitespeed.io/lib/analyze/webpagetest.js:127:14
    at WebPageTest.testCallback (/Users/.../node_modules/webpagetest/lib/webpagetest.js:346:14)
    at callbackYield (/Users/.../node_modules/webpagetest/lib/webpagetest.js:138:14)
```

And here is my configuration. It is exact your example.

```
var gulp        = require( "gulp" ),
    sitespeedio = require( "gulp-sitespeedio" );

gulp.task( "webpagetest:build", sitespeedio( {
    urls: ["http://www.sitespeed.io", "http://www.sitespeed.io/faq/"],
    noYslow: true,
    wptKey: "SECRET_KEY",
    wptHost: "www.webpagetest.org",
    no: 9,
    wptConfig: {
        location: "Dulles:Firefox",
        connectivity: "3G",
        timeout: 800
    },
    budget: {
        wpt: {
            requests: 60,
            bytesIn: 1000000,
            SpeedIndex: 1000
        }
    }
} ) );
```

node-version: v5.1.0
npm-version: v3.3.12
gulp-version: CLI v3.9.0 // LOCAL 3.9.1

Thanks for any help...

Answer (score 1):

The wptHost should use a https connection:

```
wptHost: "https://www.webpagetest.org/"
```